# SDImageCache placeholder gif

Tags: ios, objective-c, gif, sdwebimage

I am trying to create a gif as a place holder for my `SDImageCache`.

So first off I created the gif:

```
    _imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width,
                                                              cell.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.height)];
    _imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00000"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00000"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00001"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00002"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00003"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00004"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00005"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00006"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00007"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00008"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00009"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00010"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00011"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00012"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00013"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Polygon 1 copy.bolt_00014.png"], nil];
    _imageView.animationRepeatCount = 500;
```

I then turned it into an `UIimage`

```
UIImage *imagety = _imageView.image; // get the UIImage
UIImage *otherImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Loadimage.png"]; // load another image
_imageView.image = otherImage; // change in the image in your UIImageView
```

following that I put it as the placeholder:

```
 SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
    [imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:encodedString done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

        if (image){
            cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;
        }else{
            [cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedString] placeholderImage:imagety completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                [imageCache storeImage:image forKey:encodedString]; 
            }];
        }
    }];
```

But this does not seem to work? Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: could you elaborate more on what is not working exactly? the placeholder image is not displayed, is it?

Comment: The placeholder image is not displayed! Correct

Answer (score 0):

If you check the value returned by `_imageView.image`:

```
UIImage *imagety = _imageView.image;
```

you should see that it is `nil`. This is due to your using `animationImages` to handle an animation through the view.

You cannot have a `UIImageView` (or the animation associated to it) used as a placeholder image in SDImage.

You could use:

```
UIImage *imagety = [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:
                         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:...],
                             nil]
                    duration:10.0f];
```

([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/animatedImageWithImages:duration:))

> animatedImageWithImages:duration:
>
> Creates and returns an animated image from an existing set of images.
>
> ```
>    + (UIImage *)animatedImageWithImages:(NSArray *)images duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
> ```

Comment: So is this not the way to put an animated gif as the place holder?

Comment: Can you recommend another way?